# CS8618 - Non-nullable variable must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I got a warning on the main form structure (green line under mainform)

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class mainForm : Form
    {
      public mainForm() /* The warning is here */
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

How to fix this without changing the project settings?

I don't think this a duplicated question.

Best regards,

Comment: Do you have any private/public properties declared? Just place `?` after the declaring type. This is to tell that the variable could be null. You can also assign a valute to the properties inside the constructor

Comment: I fixed all other warnings by using ? and !, but don't know how to fix this one. This is the only remaining warning. For ex I've private WebView2? webView21; Shall I move it to mainform structure?

Comment: Can you share the complete code? To see the properties inside the mainForm

Comment: Thank you Carlo Zanocco. But It's around 4000 lines of code, so it's not possible to share it.

Comment: There is some property or something that need to be declared as null as I know. Only the stuffs inside the class (when declared as nullable and not initialized) generate this warning

Comment: Thank you, I will check them one by one according to your suggestion.